# URL design of getting all posts, one post, my post and so on

Tags: php, url

I'm developing a website, and have not no idea on how to design good URL(need to avoid queries like `?userId=123`).

These are what I'm going to do

all posts:

```
/posts
```

all my posts

```
/:userI/posts  ??
/posts/:userI   ??
```

get all posts of userA

```
/:userA/posts  ??
/posts/:userA  ??
```

get one post

```
/posts/:postID
```

create a new post

```
/posts/new
```

edit a post

```
/posts/:postID/edit
```

Is there any best practices?

Comment: There's no guideline as far as I'm aware. Generally you'd want to pick a style and stick with it.

Comment: I found a blog with some best practices, it's a long read but I think it is worth it. http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks good, however, you might face a little trouble with :-

get one post

```
/posts/:postID
```

Change it to

```
/posts/:userA/:postID
```

I did it so because you might want to link a post to a user for some security reasons in your application.